# which open source java library I can use to build a Bayesian network?

Tags: java, bayesian-networks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Library for Bayesian Networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483498/library-for-bayesian-networks)

which opensource library I can use to build a Bayesian network?
I need a java library that builds a Bayesian network and I need to access the values ​​of the conditional probability of CPT.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Bayesian Network Tools in Java http://bnj.sourceforge.net/ might suite your needs.

Regards,